# Azure Devops - .NET 4.7.2 - error MC3050: Cannot find the type 'VsBrushes'

Tags: c#, powershell, azure-pipelines, .net-framework-version

I try to build a .NET project (Framework 4.7.2) on a Azure Devops build server

As I build it on my pc (VS2019 or msbuild), it works fine, but as I use the same commands on the build server, I get those errors.

the only thing difference I see so far is the msbuild version

- on my pc : 16.8.3.61104
- on build server : 16.8.3+39993bd9d

Here is how I build the project in Yaml

```
msbuild MyApp.csproj /property:Configuration=Release
```

I tried a restore before the build

```
dotnet restore
Get-ChildItem .\ -include obj -Recurse | foreach { remove-item $_.fullname -Force -Recurse }
```

I feel there is something missing in the environement

I also tried to add

```
# Add Visual Studio environment variables to PowerShell: https://intellitect.com/enter- vsdevshell-powershell/
Write-Host "Adding Visual Studio environment variables to PowerShell"
Import-Module "C:\DevStudio\Vs2019\Common7\Tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll"
Enter-VsDevShell -VsInstallPath C:\DevStudio\Vs2019 -SkipAutomaticLocation
```

here is the build log

```
##[section]Starting: Build project
==============================================================================
Task         : PowerShell
Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
Version      : 2.180.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
##[command]"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". '****************.ps1'"
Adding Visual Studio environment variables to PowerShell
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2019 Developer PowerShell v16.8.5
** Copyright (c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored ********\MyApp.csproj (in 379 ms).
msbuild
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.3+39993bd9d for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 3/20/2023 10:14:51 AM.
Project "********\MyApp.csproj" on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "obj\Release\".
E:\********\SomeControl.xaml(11,14): error MC3050: Cannot find the type 'VsBrushes'. Note that type names are case sensitive. [********\MyApp.csproj]
E:\********\SomeOtherControl.xaml(15,14): error MC3050: Cannot find the type 'VsBrushes'. Note that type names are case sensitive. [********\MyApp.csproj]
E:\********\YetAnotherControl.xaml(10,14): error MC3050: Cannot find the type 'VsBrushes'. Note that type names are case sensitive. [********\MyApp.csproj]
Done Building Project "********\MyApp.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"********\MyApp.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
(MarkupCompilePass1 target) -> 
  E:\********\SomeControl.xaml(11,14): error MC3050: Cannot find the type 'VsBrushes'. Note that type names are case sensitive. [********\MyApp.csproj]
  E:\********\SomeOtherControl.xaml(15,14): error MC3050: Cannot find the type 'VsBrushes'. Note that type names are case sensitive. [********\MyApp.csproj]
  E:\********\YetAnotherControl.xaml(10,14): error MC3050: Cannot find the type 'VsBrushes'. Note that type names are case sensitive. [********\MyApp.csproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    3 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.68
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
##[section]Finishing: Build project
```

As I check the source code, the following warnings are legit since these values should be replaced at runtime

[image]

- How come the VsBrushes are not recognized when compiling the markup files ?
- what should I check to further my investigation ?

thanks for helping me on this

Comment: Microsoft developed CORE so that same code would work on Windows, Linux, and MAC without changes.  Net solution will compile on Windows but may not compile on Linux, or MAC.  It is best to move to Core 6 or 7 so code will always compile.  Libraries were change in Core so they would work on all three OS.  Your build says "Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows" which is not consistent with Net 4.7.2.

Comment: both machines are windows

Comment: Are the target version of Net the same?  Is vsshell installed? : https://github.com/egor-tensin/vs-shell?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `dotnet restore` you must add `/restore` or `-restore` to your `msbuild` command.

References:

- [MSBuild Command-Line Reference - MSBuild | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022).